# Control WMV or MPG on IE6 with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, media-player, internet-explorer-6, wmv

I have searched a long time for the title above. I want to control Videos running with the Media Player (default installed on WIN XP) on IE7 without any other plugin (these are the requirements of the target computer).
I want have a step by step documentation of a technical product on a leftbar, and onclick of this steps a video on the rightbar appears. So the problem is, the step by step documentation should go on if the video is finished (so you will redirect to the next step). So I have to write a JavaScript to check the videos running time and videos duration (in metadata). I didn´t find anything.

Does anybody know a solution?

Comment: only old IE, or does it have to work on real browsers also?

Comment: you can use the WMP controls ex ( Player.controls.next()) to .play(), .pause(), and .stop() the media player control. you can use events instead of a schedule, which is a good idea since if someone pauses a video to go to the bathroom, it won't be playing the next video when they get back...  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537508(v=vs.85).aspx#appendix for general info on embeding. i belive the api used in browser is the same as the html view example code used here: http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windowsmedia/howto/articles/htmlviewsupport.aspx

Comment: The problem is not solved yet. I have to do this now for IE8 but that changes nothing, because HTML5 video can´t be used in IE8. So I have to jump to a specific time and get the current time of the video without flash.
I found out that SMIL is an option but I didn´t find any examples for this.
So now I´m standing at the point like the last month...
Can you give me an example how to realize the controlling?